# Non printing characters

Tags: bash, terminal

I would love to get the mappings to work for keyboard shortcuts shown here 
http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences.php 
 I have the hang of color but for some reason nothing else seems to work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those codes are primarily for ANSI.SYS, a DOS extension. The equivalent for BASH is to rebind the keys via readline. See the `bash(1)` man page, **READLINE** section.

Comment: So what your saying is I can`t turn my friends caps lock key on when he reads my GIT readme